# how to detect orientation of android device?

Tags: android, orientation

Is it possible simple to detect current orientation of android device, without programming a listener and handling the position matrix?
In my app I want only to know current orientation - vertical or horizontal - at the moment. However I don't want to listen to events of axiometry or other events.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the [`getRotation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29) method:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

From the documentation:

> Returns the rotation of the screen from its "natural" orientation. The returned value may be `Surface.ROTATION_0` (no rotation), `Surface.ROTATION_90`, `Surface.ROTATION_180`, or `Surface.ROTATION_270`. For example, if a device has a naturally tall screen, and the user has turned it on its side to go into a landscape orientation, the value returned here may be either `Surface.ROTATION_90` or `Surface.ROTATION_270` depending on the direction it was turned. The angle is the rotation of the drawn graphics on the screen, which is the opposite direction of the physical rotation of the device. For example, if the device is rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise, to compensate rendering will be rotated by 90 degrees clockwise and thus the returned value here will be `Surface.ROTATION_90`.

Keep in mind that `getRotation` was introduced from Android 2.2. Use `getOrientation` if your target are older devices.

Comment: did it the job if user switch off the rotation? For example I have switch off the rotation, so my desktop orientation is always portrait, but the camera app, rotate the preview independet of this configuration.

Comment: This works on my phone - Galaxy S3, but NOT on my 10 inch tablet emulator with Android 4.3: getRotation() returns exactly opposite rotation than the actual one (landscape - portrait)!

Comment: @Yar May be your tablet emulator's starting orientation is in portrait so this code gives you exactly opposite results. Follow biegleux's answer instead

Answer (score 76):

You can also use:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

Comment: I know this is a bit of an older post, but in case one's working with a compass, the device must know the exact rotation to add or substract the correct value to get the correct bearing, so your anwser isn't the best, yet still useful.

Comment: This doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy S5. Best solution is Cristian's answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think the safest and easiest way is to add a tag for some element of your activity in XML.  For example, set the viewpager's tag to "portrait" in the portrait layout and set it to "landscape" in in landscape. Then in your oncreate check for that tag like so:

```
if(mViewpager.getTag().equals("portrait"))
  // is in portrait
else
  // is in landscape
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to know the height and the width of your canvas... your surface... your monitor... etc.

maybe you can get it with :

```
if (canvas.getHeight()>canvas.getWidth() ) {
//portrait
}
else
{
//landscape
}
```

Comment: well, i would not depend on such a thing. What `canvas` is this? Is it in a layout, what are it's layout parameters and who uses the layout in what situations... Way too many questions with a 'W' for a functionality that seems quite hardware-bound.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an extension function from the code above:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.getRotation(): Int{
    val display = (baseContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager).defaultDisplay
    val rotation = display.rotation
    when(rotation){
        Surface.ROTATION_90 -> return R.integer.LANDSCAPE
        Surface.ROTATION_270 -> return R.integer.LANDSCAPE
        Surface.ROTATION_180 -> return R.integer.PORTRAIT
        Surface.ROTATION_0 -> return R.integer.PORTRAIT
        else ->
            return R.integer.PORTRAIT
    }
}
```

In your resource directory create a `constants.xml` file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="LANDSCAPE">0</integer>
    <integer name="PORTRAIT">1</integer>
</resources>
```

You code is then as easy as (e.g. vertical / horizontal layout for a Recyclerview in a Fragment:

```
val a  = activity as AppCompatActivity
        val orientation = a.getRotation()
        when (orientation){
            R.integer.PORTRAIT -> rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
            R.integer.LANDSCAPE -> rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant, but if by chance you need to know this because you want to lock the device into its’ current orientation you can toggle between the following two lines of code.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
```