# How to globally lock Android device screen orientation

Tags: java, android, frameworks

I want to lock screen to landscape or patriot mode for all apps on my Android device.
What should I do beside disable auto screen orientation?

I have check out some apps from android market and try to see what they do.
It seems those apps create an service to manipulate WindowManager like this.

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getSystemService(CONTEXT.WINDOW_SERVICE);
CustomLayout cl = new CustomLayout(desire_orientation);
View localView = new View(this);
wm.addView(localView, cl);
```

But when I fail to do something like this. Any idea?

Also, I am able to change framework code, from Java to C++, any other way to do this?

Comment: You can try this
[link ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112118/how-to-detect-orientation-of-android-device

Comment: Potentially locking other apps' functionality doesn't sound like something the Android platform would allow. I could be wrong though!

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
wm.addView(localView, params);
```

this works for me.

Comment: Thankyou that was useful ! but now i have a problem ,when i rotate phone in portrait mode then close the window it will be appear again