# Handle screen orientation changes

Tags: java, android

I added this in my onCreate method.

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

And now I want to determine which side user is trying to rotate the phone. How can I do that?

The user can't rotate the screen, but I want to determine weather he is trying or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

I think this helpful for you: [how to detect orientation of android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112118/how-to-detect-orientation-of-android-device)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```