# Android: Only rotate webview, not the menu buttons on the phone

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin, webview

In my app I am displaying a webpage that is too big to fit on a portrait display, so I want to rotate it. I tried using `RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;` on the activity but it changes the rotation for the entire phone, rather than just the webview. I also tried making a custom webview class:

```
 public class VerticalWebView : WebView
    {
        bool topDown = true;

    public VerticalWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {

        }


        public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            if (topDown)
            {
                canvas.Translate(Height, 0);
                canvas.Rotate(90);
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.Translate(0, Width);
                canvas.Rotate(-90);
            }

            canvas.ClipRect(0, 0, Width, Height, Region.Op.Replace);
            base.Draw(canvas);
        }
    }
```

but i cannot get it to work with the webview XML in the layout file. Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I may be wrong, which is why I am just putting this as a comment, but I don't think you can individually rotate just one thing. I believe you have to rotate the entire display.

Comment: i find it hard to believe that would be the case

Comment: If you can, maybe provide some mock-up images of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I cant but it should be pretty self explanatory...i want the webpage to be shown sideways rather than straight up and down. Basically the affect you get when you rotate your phone, and the webpage rotates. I want that. Only with the phone still in an upright position

Answer (score 0):

correct me if i got your requirement wrong

First direct the orientation of the phone 
[how to detect orientation of android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112118/how-to-detect-orientation-of-android-device)

check it and inside the right condition

rotate `webView`  as you want! like below

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android");
        webView.setRotation(90);
```

dummy result be like >
[image]

Comment: this is good in theory, but it is not changign the dimensions of the webview. So when you rotate it, I get the same narrow portrait display, just laid on its side. Rather than it filling up the app (like when you actually rotate your phone)

Comment: then what about keeping the web view as rotated and change your other views rotation manually(like buttons) ,in the other way around ?