# How does one detect orientation of an Android device?

Tags: android

To get orientation, I have tried the below codes. But I don't get the desired output.

```
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

and

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

I have tried this both of code and rotate the device every angle but always get rotation value 0.

Then I have tried this below code

```
int rotation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

But now I am always getting rotation value 1.
How I will get different value of rotation for Natural orientation, Landscape left, Upside down, Landscape right?

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112118/how-to-detect-orientation-of-android-device regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getRequestedOrientation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getRequestedOrientation%28%29) and it will return one of [these values](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#screenOrientation).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Comment: I have tried this but get a compilation error like "Non-static method 'getResources() can not be referenced from a static context'" . Then I have tried this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation and this.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation, it doesn't solve my problem.