# How to hide button in landscape mode when using Databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a view that uses `DataBinding` to display data from a `ViewModel`. The view has a button that is hidden when the view is in landscape mode. At the moment this works by having two layoutfiles, but I would like to only have one as it's a nightmare to refactor. But how to go about this using `DataBinding` and `BindingAdapters`?

How do you enable the following bindingexpression for a given view?

`android:visibility="@{isLandscapeMode ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"`

EDIT:

My extension property definition (`ViewUtils.kt`):

```
val View.isLandscapeMode: Boolean
    get() = resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

And my layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <import type="com.example.base.views.ViewUtilsKt" />
        <variable
            name="isLandscapeMode "
            type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.ui.task.TaskViewModel" />
    </data>

    ...

    <ImageButton
            ...
            android:visibility="@{isLandscapeMode ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"
            ...
            />
```

This causes a compile error: `Cause: not a valid name: isLandscapeMode`

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @Khemraj Where/how do you create the isLandscapeMode function to be able to use it in a bindingexpression as above?

Comment: You can make it in ViewModel class.

Comment: Is it possible to use an extension function on View? I'm using kotlin. I'd rather not have it in my ViewModel.

Comment: Sure, you can put it in Util class. and access it in layout like - `Util.isLandscapeMode()`.

Comment: Gives me a compile error. I've edited my question.

Comment: You can not use it as an extension, but as an regular method. Then you would call like `ViewUtilsKt.isLandscapeMode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check in your binding adapter which phone orientation is currently on. Here is another post where you can find answer to your question [how to detect orientation of android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112118/how-to-detect-orientation-of-android-device)

EDIT:

You need to detect orientation and save it as boolean value. Later you have to pass that variable to your adapter which in this case will be boolean.

```
<data>

<import type="android.view.View"/>

<variable
    name="isLandscapeMode"
    type="boolean"/>

</data>
```

Comment: I know how to detect orientation. The question relates to how the bindingexpression is enabled. ie. how are you able to do `android:visibility="@{isLandscapeMode ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"`

Comment: You should include that information in original question. I have edited my answer

Comment: If only the view would render correctly. It keeps showing the button I'm trying to hide :(

Comment: Should we use a boolean variable or `MutableLiveData<Boolean>`?

Answer (score 0):

For others if they need same behavior. There are two solutions.

**First solution** (create a `BindingAdapter` and use it on the UI element of your choice):

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:visibleInLandscapeMode")
fun View.setVisibleInLandscapeMode(visible: Boolean) {
    Timber.d("setVisibleInLandscapeMode() returns ${resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE}")
    visibility = if (visible && (resources.configuration.orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)) VISIBLE else INVISIBLE
}
```

In your XML layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example">

    ...

    <ImageButton
        ...
        bind:visibleInLandscapeMode="false"
        ...
        />
```

**Second solution** (create a bindingexpression that changes the visibility of the UI element):

```
<ImageButton
    ...
    android:visibility="@{context.getResources.getConfiguration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"
    ...
    />
```

Remember the correct imports:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <import type="android.content.res.Resources" />
        <import type="android.content.res.Configuration" />
        ...
    </data>
    ...
```

Btw. be careful when using Databinding with [AndroidAnnotation](http://androidannotations.org/). See issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68892352) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73592527).